# GAE python: how to configure folder in app yaml?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting this error:

```
   raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/dist/index.html'
```

In my app.yaml file, I tried:

```
- url: /html
  static_dir: dist/html

- url: /assets
  static_dir: dist/assets

- url: /dist\.*
  script: main.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

main.py:

```
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "/dist")
```

When rendering the html files in my handler, I don't seem to be able to access the files. Within my dist folder, there are css, images and html files that I want to be able to use.

What am I doing wrong? How to setup the app.yaml file to access the files? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "/dist")
```

to

```
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dist")
```